# What are alternatives for deodorant?

Tags: alternatives, packaging, personal-hygiene

There must be natural alternatives for deodorant that at least to some degree help in covering body odor caused by perspiration. I have tried to live without antiperspirant, but I don't consider it feasible even when showering more often than once a day.
I of course prefer a self-contained natural solution that I don't have to purchase from a store.

Liquid (roll-on, cream) and solid deodorants are more environmental-friendly than aerosol sprays, but often suffer from overpackaging; I've owned products that weigh like lead.

Comment: Your body odor is influenced by what you eat. http://www.livestrong.com/article/155243-foods-to-eliminate-body-odor/

Answer (score 1):

## Baking Soda

[baking soda is said to be a great alternative to deodorant](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/261/3293).

## Aloe Vera

I myself sometimes use aloe vera. It stays moist a little longer, but the you'll also protect your skin as well.

## Mother Dirt

Someone also spoke about a thing called [mother dirt](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/5233/3293) which would prevent corporal odors to develop by replacing ill-smelling bacteria

Answer (score -2):

First sweat does not smell much until bacteria work on it, so an anti bacterial like coconut oil combined with a very small amount of another anti bacterial essential oil might work very well. Note, more than one essential oil might be used such as cloves or lemon and so forth.

Anti sweating agents should never be used since they are poisons especially do not use anything with aluminum in it in any form.